Intel BE200 on N100 with Ubuntu server
I installed an Intel BE200 WiFi card on my ASRock N100DC-ITX home server, in the M.2 slot. On a fresh Ubuntu server install, the card does not seem to be recognised. I can connect via cable but not over Wi-Fi.
System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-49-generic x86_64)
lspci --nk shows one internet-related entry, which is I think not the wifi card.
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many) [1849:8168]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

ip a, nmcli and iwconfig shows only three non-wireless interfaces lo, docker0 and enp1s0. iwconfig adds no wireless extensions. to each.
modprobe iwlwifi does not give any feedback and changes nothing.
dmesg has nothing on “wifi” or “wire”.
rfkill isn't even installed.
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 9c:6b:00:62:ac:31
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-49-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.2.88 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:80904000-80904fff memory:80900000-80903fff

How can I check whether the card is broken, or unsupported, or switched off?
--
I just now tested with Ubuntu live, this also did not recognize the card. I cannot find it in the BIOS either. I think the card is defective.

What does iwconfig show?

Is wifi/WLAN enabled in BIOS?  Appears that only the onboard ethernet is detected

@stumblebee I added the result in the question.

@Jeremy31 I couldn't find anything in the BIOS, will check again but there's probably no entry on WiFi there.

Found it. BE200 is PCI Express, which isn't compatible on a hardware level. Should have bought the BE201.
ASRock docs note


1 x M.2 Socket (Key E), supports type 2230 Intel® CNVio (Integrated WiFi/BT) - M.2 PCI Express module is not supported


Intel docs though say

System Interface Type: M.2: PCIe*, USB

